# Open Street Map (OSM) Geocoding not returning addresses/coordinates in R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, geocoding, geocode, nominatim

In an attempt to migrate away from the Google Geocoding API because of their terms, I looked into the `nominatim` [package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim) and the OpenStreetMap API, specifically for geocoding. However, fairly simple addresses return no results. Even the code from the `osm_geocode` example misses addresses. Am I doing something wrong?

I followed the instructions and registered for a free API key [here](https://developer.mapquest.com). See code:

```
# Set my API key
osmKey <- "insert your key"

# Geocode a very famous address, exact code taken from GitHub page
osm_geocode("1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC.", key = osmKey)
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

It doesn't matter if I remove the `.` after the `DC.`. I even chose an address I went to recently with the ISO 3166-1alpha2 country code, knowing very well it exists:

```
osm_geocode("90 Washington St, New York, NY", country_codes = "us", key = osmKey)

# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

For confirmation that some addresses work:

```
osm_geocode("Washington, DC.", key = osmKey)

place_id                                                                              licence osm_type  osm_id
1 187983016 Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright relation 5396194
       lat       lon                                               display_name class type importance
1 38.89495 -77.03665 Washington, District of Columbia, United States of America place city  0.2891642
                                                                                                    icon bbox_left
1 http://ip-10-98-176-55.mq-us-east-1.ec2.aolcloud.net/nominatim/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png  38.79163
  bbox_top bbox_right bbox_bottom
1 38.99585  -77.11977   -76.90937
```

So the API works, but specific addresses don't. I heard this was a reliable API. Can anyone help with assistance? Why aren't my street addresses working?

Comment: The package has an open issue on this: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/issues/15

Comment: @Camille thank you. I am still learning the GitHub outline. I now know that the I can see issues on the issues tab. It doesn't look like it would be resolved soon, as the issue was addressed in 2018.  Looks like I have to seek another option.